# Calling a function to change an objects position in an array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I'm trying to figure out how I can use a function to change the array index value of an object when a function is called and I can't figure out how to do it. Here's what I have so far:

```
var direction = ["North","East","South","West"];

var car = function() {
/* Class Constructor */
    this.cardinal = 0;
    this.currentDirection = direction[this.cardinal];
    this.showDirection = compass;
    this.turnRight = rightTurn;

function compass()
{
    document.write("<li>" + this.name + " is going " + this.direction + ".</li>");
}
function rightTurn()
{
    if (this.cardinal < 4) {
        this.cardinal = this.cardinal + 1;
        this.showDirection();
} else {
    this.cardinal = 0;
    this.showDirection();
}    
}

} // end car constructor

pontiac    = new car();
```

Later I call the function buy using this

```
pontiac.turnRight();
```

The object does have a bit more to it but I removed that section to make it easier to read. I can add the additional bits if needed but I don't think it's really relevant to this. I know I'm doing the rightTurn() function incorrectly. I used the if else loop because I need it to go back to North if the car is on West (since it's the last position of the array)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have a `this.direction` property and a global `direction` array (that should stay constant). Don't confuse the two.

Comment: Do you want your `this.direction` property to be a string (like the array contents) or an integer (so that you can increment it)? Choose one.

Comment: If I put it under the car variable would it solve this? If I run compass(); it does successfully show it as North.

Comment: Looks much better after your latest edit. Now you just need to use `this.currentDirection` instead of `this.direction` in `compass`/`showDirection`, and you will need to update `this.currentDirection = direction[this.cardinal];` after having assigned the new `cardinal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you

```
var car = function() {
        /* Class Constructor */
        this.directions = ["North","East","South","West"];
        this.currentIndex = 0;
        this.showDirection = compass;
        this.turnRight = rightTurn;
        this.name = "car"
        function compass()
        {   
            document.write("<li>" + this.name + " is going " + this.directions[this.currentIndex] + ".</li>");
        }

        function rightTurn()
        {   
            if (this.currentIndex == (this.directions.length-1)) {
                this.currentIndex = 0;
                this.showDirection();
            } else {
                this.currentIndex++;
                this.showDirection();
            }
        }
    } // end car constructor

    pontiac    = new car();
    pontiac.turnRight()
```

every time you call pontiac.turnRight() you will set the current direction to right element beside, and when you get to "west" yo will go back to "North".

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When `this.cardinal` is 3,

> ```
> if (this.cardinal < 4) {
>     this.cardinal = this.cardinal + 1;
> ```

lets it become 4, indexing out of the array (valid indices are 0, 1, 2 and 3).
So you need 3 in the comparison:

```
if (this.cardinal < 3) {
    this.cardinal = this.cardinal + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `this.direction` needs to be `this.direction` everywhere inside your class. If I were you I'd change the name of your your array from `direction` to `cardinals` or something, so you don't confuse yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to simplify things but in the rightTurn() function I'm still having trouble with pulling the current placement in the array and either incrementing to the next array value or setting it back to [0] if the array is currently on [3]